# Connecting R Shiny to R Script with Function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a script called function.R which contains a function called `my_function` that generates an output.

```
my_function <- function(a, b, c) {
  # code
}
```

How can I get the user to input values for a,b,c in a r shiny app and then these inputs can be delivered to my function.R script. I want the shiny app to take in the inputs for each of these values (a,b,c) and then send it to my function.R script so it can show the output of my function in the r shiny app.

My r shiny app is

```
library(shiny)

source("/Users/havekqnsc/Desktop/function.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Function Output"),
  numericInput("a", "a", value = ""),
  numericInput("b", "b", value = ""),
  textInput("c", "c", value = ""),
  actionButton("Submit", "RunFunction")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    my_function()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You need to pass the input values when calling the function `observeEvent(input$Submit, {myfunction(a=input$a, b=input$b, c=input$c)})`

Comment: @MrFlick thank you! And then do I also need to have like an output variable or something? After that

Comment: What kind of output does it return? Yes you'd want to have some sort of place to put the output in your UI.

Comment: @MrFlick the final output  of the function is a data frame, data table

Comment: Then you’re better to use a reactive that references the submit button (and the other inputs) rather than an `observeEvent`. That way, you can simply pass the reactive to a `renderTable` to display it.

Comment: @Limey thank you! How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Call the function inside a reactive/eventReactive and store the result.
2. Call the reactive inside a renderTable function.

```
library(shiny)

#example function
my_function <- function(a, b, c) {
  data.frame(a = a, b = b, c = c)
}
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Function Output"),
  numericInput("a", "a", value = ""),
  numericInput("b", "b", value = ""),
  textInput("c", "c", value = ""),
  actionButton("Submit", "RunFunction"),
  tableOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  result <- eventReactive(input$Submit, {
    my_function(input$a, input$b, input$c)
  })
  
  output$result <- renderTable({
    result()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```